# New Karate Plugin update is giving issue in intelliJ

Tags: karate, intellij-plugin

"""
@custUpdWorkflow
Scenario Outline:
* def ScenarioName = ''
* def requestBody = schemaJson.requestBody
* set requestBody.iv_request.reference_no = Java.type('DateFormat').generateReferenceNumber()
* def filteredData = filterNullAndEmptyArray(requestBody)
* print filteredData
* call read('classpath:templates/custUpdateTemplate.feature@t_custUpdate'){payload : #(filteredData)}
* match response == schemaJson.responseSchemaForSuccess
* def Message = response.et_message[0].message
* print 'Message: ',Message
* match response == schemaJson.responseSchemaForSuccess
* print response

```
Examples:
  | read('classpath:schemas/UPDCust.csv') |
```

"""

after i installed updated Karate plugin in intelliJ, error is ' expected, got '#': 40' at place #(filteredData).

Comment: can you please log such issues here: https://github.com/karatelabs/intellij-plugin/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `{ payload : #(filteredData) }` is invalid JSON. Please change it to: `{ payload : '#(filteredData)' }`.

Yes the parser behind the scenes is lenient to some extent, but nowhere in the Karate documentation or examples have we removed the quotes.